# Django login and register : 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I write login and register form and I use my database (NOT DJANGO's DATABASE).

File **models.py**:

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

 class Student (AbstractBaseUser):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      first_name= models.CharField(max_length=250)
      last_name= models.CharField(max_length=250)
      gender= models.CharField(max_length=250)
      telNo = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

File **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Student

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    # email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    telNo = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'color: black;','placeholder':'تلفن همراه'}),
        label='تلفن همراه',
        error_messages={'required': "تلفن همراه خود را وارد کنید"})
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = (
            'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'telNo',
            'password', 'confirm_password'
        )

        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(Student, self).clean()
            password = cleaned_data.get("password")
            confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

            if password != confirm_password:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "password and confirm_password does not match"
                )

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'color: black;','placeholder':'ایمیل یا شماره دانشجویی'}),
        label='نام کاربری',
        error_messages={'required': "فیلد را پر کنید"})
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'style': 'color: black;','placeholder':'رمز عبور'}),
        label='رمز عبور',
        error_messages={'required': "فیلد را پر کنید"})
```

File **views.py**:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            print(user)
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})

def login(request):
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username','')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password','')
        stud = Student.objects.get(username=username)
        stud.set_password(stud.password)
        stud.save()
        stud = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        # print(user)
        auth.login(request, stud)

    return render(request,"registration/login.html",{'form':form})
```

File **settings.py**:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'jbja9viev6kskq8()1@m-xh$n91oc!kemw2%a0^#2$=+lxauiv'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://www.google.com/'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'llr.apps.LlrConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testLogin.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testLogin.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

I don't no why I receive the error:

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I use `set_password` for hashing password. Also I receive `None` from `authenticate()`.

Can you help me ?